# Numbers on clusters aren't displayed

Tags: openlayers, cluster-analysis

I am developing an app using OpenLayers.

In the loading process I am running the app and everything is going fine. However, the labels on the clusters that show the number of crimes on each cluster don't show up.

Here is the code for the clustering, where the map is loading fine.

```
 this.addCrimesToMap = function (){
        // Create a vector layers
        var vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Features", {
            renderers: ['Canvas','SVG'],
            strategies: [
                new OpenLayers.Strategy.AnimatedCluster({
                    distance: 45,
                    animationMethod: OpenLayers.Easing.Expo.easeOut,
                    animationDuration: 20
                })
            ],
            styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                'default': {
                    graphicWidth: 25,
                    graphicHeight: 25,
                    label: "",

                    fontColor: "black",
                    fontSize: "12px",
                    fontFamily: "Arial",
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    labelAlign: "c", //"l" - left, "r" - right, "c" - center , "m" - midle, "t" - top, "b" - bottom
                    labelXOffset: "15",
                    labelYOffset: "0",
                    labelOutlineColor: "white",
                    labelOutlineWidth: 3,
                    externalGraphic: "common/images/map/event_small.png",
                    display: "yes"
                }
            })
            //styleMap:  new OpenLayers.StyleMap(style)
        });
        map.addLayer(vector);

        // Create some random features
        var features = [];
        for (var i=0; i< 5000; i++) {

            var lon = Math.random() * (34.81-34.75) + 34.75;
            var lat = Math.random() * (31.28-31.21) + 31.21;

            var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat);

            lonlat.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"));

            var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lonlat.lon, lonlat.lat);

            var f = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point);
            features.push(f);
        }
        vector.addFeatures(features);
    };
```

If I do it without a styleMap, all I can see are the clusters without labels.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You will need to provide a complete example to debug this. The example here, http://acuriousanimal.com/code/animatedCluster/, works, without an stylemap, so it is likely your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I saw this example. In the example i can see the mapStyle, however it is not defined in this example. So i think that i am missing something...

Comment: Without a jsfiddle it is hard to know.